# ruby - multiple if statements (if @var is defined)

Tags: ruby

How would I go about doing the following:

- taking user input, could be any number of 'tags'
- evaluating, for each tag, if @tag is defined, and if it is, if the *key* and *value* are equal
- if the above conditions pass, then add to an array

Sample(incorrect) code:

```
@array1.each do |element|
    if ( @tag1 && ( @tag1 == @value1 ) ) &&
    if ( @tag2 && ( @tag2 == @value2 ) ) &&
    if ( @tag3 && ( @tag3 == @value3 ) ) &&
    if ( @tag4 && ( @tag4 == @value4 ) )
    @array2 << element
end
```

I want to add `element` to an array, but only if each tag is defined, and only if @tag == @value. For example:

if @tag2 is defined, and @tag2 == @value2 AND
if @tag3 is defined, and @tag3 == @value3

add `element` to the array.

The above code will add `element` *twice*, and I only want it added once.

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks

EDIT:

tag and value are not part of an array. They are using the ruby aws-sdk. Perhaps to make it clear, `element` will be the instance-id of an AWS instance. The instance will have a series of tags on it. I want to return an instance-id ONLY if it has a tag (passed in as `ruby script.rb --tag1`) and ONLY if tag1 == value1 (`ruby script.rb --tag1 value1`). However I want this to happen if other tags are found too.

The problem is that if 2 tages are passed in:

```
ruby script.rb --tag1 value1 --tag2 value2
```

Then 
    `if ( @tag1 && ( @tag1 == @value1 ) ) &&`
is TRUE, and
    `if ( @tag2 && ( @tag2 == @value2 ) ) &&`
is TRUE, element is added twice. I only want it added once.

Comment: What you want to achieve would have been more clear if you could also add the values of `@array1`, `@tag*` and `@value*`.

Comment: Understood, but the values are coming from API calls that I wouldn't be able to demonstrate here. I was hoping that someone could see the error in the logic. I could mock some sample values though if that helps

Comment: tag and value both are stored in array? They are part of array?

Comment: If they are not than please make it more clear or your problem is you are getting element twice, you may  call .uniq on it that would solve your problem

Comment: I edited my post. I hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, it's no need to check if `@tag1` exists, since `nil == 'SomeValue'` is `false`.

If I understand your question correctly, here is solution:

Use `Set` instead of `Array`. Items in `Set` are always unique.

```
set = Set.new
@array1.each do |element|
  if @tag1 == @value1 && @tag2 == @value2 && @tag3 == @value3 && @tag4 == @value4
    set << element
  end
end

@array2 = set.to_a
```